# focus() works in IE 9 but not in chrome, firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I am trying to set focus on an div with a class  using `jquery.focus()`, It works in IE 9 but not in firefox or chrome.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ searchDivToggle(); $('.searchResultsFieldSet').focus();},0);
```

The page has search form,table with search results, each row has a link to view details, click on link shows details div  hiding search form  and table, details div has close on click hide details show search and search results.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fachhoch/2e393fju/)

html

```
<html>
    <head>
             <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                function showDetails(){
                    $('#search').toggle();
                    $('#detailsFragment').css("display","block");
                }
                function hideDetails(){
                    $('#search').toggle();
                    $('#detailsFragment').css("display","none");
                    $('#searchResults').focus();
                }
            </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div  id="search">  
        <div style="height:50em;  width=30em; border-width: 1px; border-style: dotted; padding-bottom: 1em; padding-top: 1em; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em ">

            Place hodler for search form........
        </div>

    <div style="border-width: 1px; border-style: dotted; padding-bottom: 1em; padding-top: 1em; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em ">
        <label  style=" font-weight: bold;" >Search Results </label>    
        <table  id="searchResults">

            <thead>
                <td>column1</td>
                <td>column2</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </thead     
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some value...
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showDetails();">Show Details</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>        

        </table>
    </div>  
    </div>
        <div   id="detailsFragment"  style="display:none">
            <div style="height:50em;  width=30em; border-width: 1px; border-style: dotted; padding-bottom: 1em; padding-top: 1em; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em ">
                    Details Fragment 
                    <input type="button" value="Close"   onclick="hideDetails();">
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: How do you imagine brining focus to a table would work? It's not an interactive element, elements you can bring into focus are things like buttons, links and form inputs.

Comment: Maybe you need to scroll to the table instead of fire `focus` event.

Answer (score 1):

The `focus()` cannot be place on a `table` element. It needs to be place on `input`, `textarea` or `select`

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (, , etc.) and links (). In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks on the element.

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

You might want to use a `scrollTo()` element function. There is one example here:
[jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: ... It needs to be place on `input`, `textarea` or *`select`*